# Вывод даты в Django

Tags: python, django

Хочу вывести читабельную дату, что-то вроде 12.02.2023 12:34.

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    date_creation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

Но такой код выводит следующий формат:

```
datetime.datetime(2023, 2, 12, 7, 28, 36, 294552, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Какие могут быть варианты?

Comment: вариант тут только один - почитать документацию python по поводу метода `strftime`.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать шаблоны Django для отображения даты в формате, который вы хотите.

В шаблоне вы можете использовать фильтр date, чтобы изменить формат даты:

```
{{ post.date_creation|date:"d.m.Y H:i" }}
```

Если вы хотите установить этот формат по умолчанию, вы можете использовать локаль в настройках Django:

```
 # settings.py

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-RU'
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```